# Can two packagist users publish packages under same vendor name?

Tags: package-managers, packagist

There are there team member in our team. One who was creating library and posting on packagist.org . Now Without him nobody can post under the vendor name .

**For example:**

Our Group name in github is "hedronium" No group members can submit any kind of under hedronium's vendor name .

Why this is happening ? And how can we prevent this?

Comment: For reference, see https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/346.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now other people can add repos under their name and set themself as maintainer.

If somebody adds a package but is not the person who owns the repository the owner should be allowed to take it back.

This could be done by a simple check against the repository. If you're a member of that repo or organization you can claim it and Packagist sets this user as maintainer.

Comment: What if you fork the original package and change it? Can you publish the newly made package? Because I'm trying to do that but it keeps saying that I'm not the contributor.